ORA-27486: Insufficient Privileges
I'm getting "ORA-27486: Insufficient privileges" error.
What grants am I missing here?
I'm executing an insert script using DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE and I'm getting getting this error in DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK
Sample script:
INSERT INTO TAB(col2, col2)
SELECT PDPT_PTY.FUNC(col1), col2
FROM TAB_PRT

I'm able to execute if I don't use PDPT_PTY.FUNC(),I mean if I just use 'col1'.
I've tried giving the grants for DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE on all the users including PDPT_PTY.


To execute chunks in parallel, you must have CREATE JOB system privilege.

Source: 123.2 from the docs.
Besides this of course you will need INSERT privilege on TAB as well as SELECT privilege on TAB_PRT.
However, given the fact that your execution fails only due to the function call, you will need the EXECUTE privilege for PDPT_PTY, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58227/ch18.htm

Thank you! Getting the grant on CREATE JOB and DBMS_SCHEDULER did the work.
